# Sidebar animation issue: Works on open but disappears without animation on close in React/Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a Menu react component where if I click on the 'hamburger' icon (which I made manually), the sidebar menu will open with an animation. The problem is that the animation works well only when opening, and when closing the sidebar disappears automatically, without any animation.

Let's take a look at the Menu component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

const Menu = ({ sidebarOpen, toggleSidebar }) => {

    const sidebarContainerRef = useRef(null);
    const sidebarElementRef = useRef(null);
    const [animationComplete, setAnimationComplete] = useState(false);

    const toggleSidebarState = () => {
        if (!sidebarOpen) {
            setAnimationComplete(false);
        }
        toggleSidebar(!sidebarOpen);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (sidebarOpen && sidebarContainerRef.current && !animationComplete) {
            const sidebarElement = sidebarElementRef.current;
            sidebarElement.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
            sidebarElement.style.transition = "transform 0s";
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                sidebarElement.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
                sidebarElement.style.transition = "transform 0.5s";
                setAnimationComplete(true);
            });
        }
    }, [sidebarOpen, animationComplete]);

    return (
        <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 w-full bg-white z-50 border-t-1 border-green-900">
            <div className="h-[60px] flex items-center justify-between">

                <div className="flex items-center ml-4">
                    <div
                        ref={sidebarContainerRef}
                        className="cursor-pointer p-3"
                        onClick={toggleSidebarState}
                    >
                        <div className={`h-1 w-6 bg-green-700 rounded mb-1 ${sidebarOpen ? 'opacity-0' : ''}`}></div>
                        <div className={`h-1 w-6 bg-green-700 rounded mb-1 ${sidebarOpen ? 'opacity-0' : ''}`}></div>
                        <div className={`h-1 w-6 bg-green-700 rounded ${sidebarOpen ? 'opacity-0' : ''}`}></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 
            </div>
            {sidebarOpen && (
                <div>
                    <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 backdrop-blur-sm"
                         onClick={() => toggleSidebar(false)}>
                    </div>
                    <div ref={sidebarElementRef} className="fixed top-0 left-0 bottom-0 z-10 w-[78%] md:max-w-[20rem] p-4 bg-white shadow-xl shadow-blue-gray-900/5 border-r-1 border-green-800">
                        <Sidebar />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
           
        </div>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

What am I not doing right? How can I solve this bug?

Answer (score 1):

The `sidebarOpen` conditional rendering you have means that the elements constituting the sidebar gets removed straight away, before any transitions happen.

Instead, consider keeping the sidebar element in the DOM and using `visibility: hidden` to hide it visually. Also, consider toggling `-translate-x-full` class name instead of the `useEffect()` for a more declarative style that React tends to lend one towards:

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;

const Sidebar = () => 'Sidebar';

const Menu = ({ sidebarOpen, toggleSidebar }) => {
  const sidebarContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const sidebarElementRef = useRef(null);

  const toggleSidebarState = () => {
    toggleSidebar(!sidebarOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 w-full bg-white z-50 border-t-1 border-green-900">
      <div className="h-[60px] flex items-center justify-between">
        <div className="flex items-center ml-4">
          <div ref={sidebarContainerRef} className="cursor-pointer p-3" onClick={toggleSidebarState}>
            <div className={`h-1 w-6 bg-green-700 rounded mb-1 ${sidebarOpen ? "opacity-0" : ""}`}></div>
            <div className={`h-1 w-6 bg-green-700 rounded mb-1 ${sidebarOpen ? "opacity-0" : ""}`}></div>
            <div className={`h-1 w-6 bg-green-700 rounded ${sidebarOpen ? "opacity-0" : ""}`}></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {sidebarOpen && (
          <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 backdrop-blur-sm" onClick={() => toggleSidebar(false)}></div>
        )}
        <div
          className={`fixed top-0 left-0 bottom-0 z-10 w-[78%] md:max-w-[20rem] p-4 bg-white shadow-xl shadow-blue-gray-900/5 border-r-1 border-green-800 duration-500 ${!sidebarOpen && '-translate-x-full invisible'}`}
        >
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [sidebarOpen, toggleSidebar] = useState(false);
  return <Menu sidebarOpen={sidebarOpen} toggleSidebar={toggleSidebar} />;
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```